filter for a certain string in a certain column otherwise another string in another column
manufacturer_status



Organization
Year
Target




ABC
2012
Achieved


ABC
2014
Partial


ABC
2015
Failed


XYZ
2014
Partial


XYZ
2015
Failed


OPQ
2012
Failed



I would like Achieved target data for each organization. If it has no Achieved target data then I Partial target data. If both Achieved and Partial are not there then no data.
Expected Output



Organization
Year
Target




ABC
2012
Achieved


XYZ
2014
Partial



I tried:
Select * from manufacturer_status where target='Achieved'

This will give only organization ABC.
Select * from manufacturer_status where target in ('Achieved', 'Partial')

This will give ABC twice, for Achieved and Partial.

You have tagged your request database, but your request is not about how to build a database. You have tagged your request database-design, but but your request is not about modelling a database. You have tagged hive and hbase and as far as I know these are two different products. You have tagged sql, but as far as I know neiter hive nor hbase feature SQL. Please correct the tags.

Agreed with Thorsten that you require some adjustments to your questioning. But I would like to point out that utilizing a GROUP BY clause along with more SQL should do the trick for you.

What is the expected output when there are multiple entries with Acheived for an organisation ? for example ABC|2013|Achieved, should the output return the latest i.e row with 2013 or oldest i.e row with 2012 or it should return both 2012 and 2013 for ABC?

I have to select other columns also in the table (Not given here). Considering that, @Charlieface second option really suits for my requirement. And others asked question what if there is a more than one row with different year. At any point only one data will be there for the organization with same target.

Looks like some conditional aggregation would do the trick
SELECT
  ms.Organization,
  ISNULL(
    MIN(CASE WHEN ms.Target = 'Achieved' THEN ms.Year END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN ms.Target = 'Partial'  THEN ms.Year END)
  ) AS Year,
  ISNULL(
    MIN(CASE WHEN ms.Target = 'Achieved' THEN ms.Target END),
    MIN(CASE WHEN ms.Target = 'Partial'  THEN ms.Target END)
  ) AS Target
FROM manufacturer_status ms
WHERE ms.Target IN ('Achieved', 'Partial')
GROUP BY
  ms.Organization;

You could also use window functions, relying on the fact that Achieved comes before Partial in the ordering.
SELECT
  ms.Organization,
  ms.Year,
  ms.Target
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ms.Organization ORDER BY ms.Target, ms.Year) AS rn
    FROM manufacturer_status ms
    WHERE ms.Target IN ('Achieved', 'Partial')
) ms
WHERE ms.rn = 1;

db<>fiddle

PostgreSQL:
Fiddle
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Organization) 
    Organization,
    Year,
    Target
FROM manufacturer_status
WHERE Target IN ('Achieved', 'Partial')
ORDER BY Organization, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Target = 'Achieved' THEN 1
        WHEN Target = 'Partial' THEN 2
    END
-- ,Year desc  
;

I commented Year in the ORDER BY but you can use it. If there are multiple rows with the same Target, the Year column is used as a secondary sort to break ties. This ensures that if there are multiple rows with the same Target, the earliest year will be selected.


Your query has a problem, if the “manufacturer_status” has ('ABC', 2013, 'Achieved'), your query skip the row.

Thanks @nik0x1, I have added -- year in the order by clause, this can be used to break ties and will fetch the earlier year

It does not solve the problem, try to insert ('ABC', 2013, 'Achieved'), your result set should to have 3 rows.

I think either  earliest/oldest year is expected and not both , there is some clarification asked in the question,lets see if thats the case, I have tried the code shared by Charlieface above, it also ignores the 2013 data for ABC, it returns only 2012

Charlieface’s code has the same problem.

yup think so, I just left a comment asking for clarification with the same example

Here is a standard SQL solution that should work in most modern RDBMSs:
select *
from manufacturer_status
where target in ('Achieved', 'Partial')
order by row_number() over (partition by organization order by target, year)
fetch first row with ties;

This numbers each organization's rows such that the best row gets #1 and orders the data to get these rows first. The WITH TIES clause ensures you get all #1 rows.

When a 'Achieved' row is added for 'ABC' then above methods do not work, we need a solution for any data that working true
select distinct Organization,Year,Target 
from 
(select * from [manufactor_status] c left join  
(select * from 
(select [Organization] o ,[Year] y, IIf([Target]='Achieved' , 'Achieved' ,'') [Target2]
from [dbo].[manufactor_status]) a
where a.Target2 !='') b
on c.Organization=b.o) d
where (d.Target=d.Target2 and d.Target='Achieved') or (d.Target='Partial' and d.Target2 is null)

when data in table is change, it is working true
